# apt-get update fails debian 7.5.0

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, wireless-networking, debian

I am a beginner at debian.

I hvae just installed debian 7.5.0 amd netinst.

When I execute apt-get update I get errors like Could not resolve 'http.debian.org'

Thus,I changed the mirrors several times in /etc/apt/sources.list but without any result.

I deduced that it is because of the absence of internet connection.

So,I executed ifconfig and ifconfig-a, the output indicates only the loopback no eth0 interface.

However the ethernet card and WLAN card are pretty detected , I checked it through lspci and both cards appear.

I edit / etc / network / interfaces by adding dhcp but it was in vain.

Please, could anybody help me as soon as possible.

Comment: Could anyone confirm that internet connection is the problem cause?

Comment: Add your network interfaces config file

Answer (score 1):

After editing the interfaces file you should run in a terminal:

```
# ifup eth0
```

Notice you don't have to type the #, it just means you run it from the root user.

**Update** if you don't have eth0 type ifconfig -a to see all the devices available. Chances are you may have one such wlan0 or something like that.

Comment: I get 
Cannot find eth0
Bind socket to interface: no such device
Failed to bring up eth0